# Get a specific value from an array list

Tags: java, arraylist

```
        while (fileScan.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = fileScan.nextLine();
            lineScan = new Scanner(line);
            int playerType = Integer.parseInt(lineScan.next());
            if (playerType == 0)
            {
                availPlayers.add(player = new Player(playerType, Integer.parseInt(lineScan.next())));
            }
            else if (playerType == 1)
            {
                availPlayers.add(vip = new VIP(playerType, Integer.parseInt(lineScan.next()), Integer.parseInt(lineScan.next()), lineScan.next(), lineScan.next()));
            }
            else if (playerType == 2)
            {
                availPlayers.add(superVip = new SuperVIP(playerType, Integer.parseInt(lineScan.next()), Integer.parseInt(lineScan.next()), lineScan.next(), lineScan.next()));
            }
        }
players.txt 
0 100
1 500 1234 Jane Smith
1 300 3455 John Smith
0 500
2 1000 9867 Hot Shot
0 200
0 300
2 2000 5555 Charles B
```

Is there a way where I can extract each individual value and set them to a variable?

```
[0 100, 1 500 1234 Jane Smith, 1 300 3455 John Smith, 0 500, 2 1000 9867 Hot Shot, 0 200, 0 300, 2 2000 5555 Charles B]
```

For example, I want to set 1, 500, 1234 to separate int variables and John and Smith each to a string variable.

Comment: What does your array stores give more details?

Comment: Yes you can do this, but do you want to search on the arraylist? Your question is not clear to me yet

Comment: i pretty want  to know if i can get the get the indexes of the indexes of the arraylist if that makes any sense. So if i get the first index of the arraylist .get(0) which will be 0 100, can i get 0 and set that to a variable and so on.

Comment: Ok, I added a solution for this could you check that please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted since the question is unclear. But from my best guess, `String.split()` just what you need.

### Example

```
String input = "1 500 1234 Jane Smith";

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

for (String s : input.split(" ")) {
    // Split the string at spaces.
    try {
        // Try parsing as an integer.
        integers.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // NumberFormatException will be thrown if the string cannot be parsed as an integer, 
        // in this case we continue to process it as a string.
        strings.add(s);
    }
}

System.out.println(strings); // ["Jane", "Smith"]
System.out.println(integers); // ["1", "500", "1234"]
```

Comment: Thank you but not quite.
ArrayList<Player> currentPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
System.out.println(currentPlayers.get(0)); // 0 100
Is there a way where i could split 0 and 100 and set them to separate variables?

Comment: @Raymond How about `String[] s = currentPlayers.get(0).split(" ");` and then `int a = Integer.parseInt(s[0]), b = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);`?

Comment: I tried that but didnt work =( i get the error message: The method split(String) is undefined for the type Player.

Comment: I am blindly guessing here, you need to give more details of the `Player` class in your question. My best guess for you is to try again with `String[] s = currentPlayers.get(0).toString().split(" ");` instead.

Comment: I already know there is now solution to what i am asking but i may have found an alternative.
Player p1 = currentPlayers.get(0); // 0 100, int id = p1.getPlayerType(); // 0, int cash = p1.getMoney()); // 100

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are holding `Player`, `VIP` and `SuperVIP` objects in your `availPlayers` `list`. And I am assuming they implement the same interface let's say `Human`. So what you can do is, you can iterate over the `availPlayers` in a loop and for all item in your list, you can get the `playerType` and according to player type you can get all the values you need via getter methods. Something like the following. Here `getIntValue` and `getStrValue` are just samples, you need to change those with your getter methods in your base class.

```
for (int i = 0; i < availPlayers.size(); i++)
  int playerType = h.getPlayerType();
  if (playerType == 0) {
    int i1 = availPlayers.get(i).getIntValue();
  }
  else if (playerType == 1) {
    String strValue = availPlayers.get(i).getStrValue();
  }
  else if (playerType == 2) {
    String strValue = availPlayers.get(i).getStrValue();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I got an idea because of your post.     static ArrayList<Player> currentPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();     static Player p1 = currentPlayers.get(0);     p1.getPlayerType();     p1.getMoney();

Comment: @RaymondKim No problem, if my answer worked for you could you please accept and upvote, thank you